# How can I add a custom commit message to this git alias?

Tags: git

`git config --global alias.a '!git commit -a -m "commit" && git push'`

Not sure how to use the !sh

Comment: Yes. I've tried with the $1 also but clearly I don't know what I'm doing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Want to use a parameter inside an alias?

Try with an adhoc bash function :

```
git config --global alias.a '!f() { git commit -am "$1" && git push; }; f'

# then use it with
git a "My message is awesome."
```

Comment: f() { !git commit -am "$1" && git push; }; f: !git: command not found

Comment: @user5531720 Sorry for the early typo, edited it already.